# Modifying non-const members of const object

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, undefined-behavior

I do know that modifying an object declared as constant is an UB. What about more complex example mentioned in the title?

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo ( void ) { }
        int data;
};

int main ( void )
{
    const Foo foo;
    const_cast<Foo&>(foo).data = 0;   //  UB?
    return 0;
}
```

`data` is declared as non-const so it's ok to modify it. But the `foo` is declared as const. So it seems we can not modify it. Thus I believe that an UB is invoked here. Am I right?

**UPDATE:** So it comes out that it's actually an UB. This means that all the classes which have fake constant members modifying mutable members produce an UB on constant instances.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        mutable int data;
        Foo ( void ) { }
        void foo ( void ) const
        {
            some_modifications_of_data();
        }
};


const Foo foo;
foo.foo(); // UB?
```

Does it mean that if you design this kind of class you must explicitly mention that under no circumstances nobody can call this method on a constant instance?

Comment: No, the object is const, so you can't modify it.

Comment: Yes, it's by the standard, undefined. It may well "work" (as in set data to zero in the way you'd expect) in your particular compiler, as that option is one of the possible outcomes of "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @chris: The `const_cast` does get rid of the `const`, so the compiler will compile this, generating some code that may or may not actually "work".

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I apologize, can't modify it and expect it to do some particular thing.

Comment: @chris, yes, that's what "UB" means, so yes...

Comment: If you need modify some values for const objects or in const methods, you can use "mutable" keyword before defining data. Then your sample will be ok (even without const_cast).

Comment: @chris thank you for an answer, I've added an update. Could you please check it out?

Comment: @MatsPetersson thank you for an answer, I've added an update. Could you please check it out?

Comment: I have added an answer that I believe covers your updated code. The second code is not UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `const_cast` to modify data in a `const` data structure is indeed undefined behaviour. The exception is items marked `mutable`. The whole point of these values are that they are modifiable even when the rest of the object is `const`. It really means "but this one is not `const`".

Since nearly all of `const` is about the compiler detecting modification, although technically, the compiler is allowed place some `const` variables in "non-writeable memory". The `mutable` keyword is there to allow "bypass" of the constness, so the compiler will NOT put a `const` object into memory that is non-writeable if it has a mutable component, and of course, it won't "object" to `const` objects being modified in it's mutable components - even inside a `const` function.